# Can longdesc be used without meaningful alt text?

Tags: html, image, accessibility, alt

I'm attempting to write good fallback text content for a webcomic. Naturally, there is a huge amount of actual text locked in the image, and plenty of descriptions/actions/expressions that could also be described. Having `longdesc="#transcript"` seems like the perfect use case, and comes with benefits for searching and automatic translation.

But what do I do with the `alt`? I've checked the official specs, and dug around in WebAIM and similar sites, but I've never seen a use case for having `longdesc` supplant `alt`. This makes sense for the usual applications (overview a chart in the alt text, link to a full breakdown elsewhere), but it seems like any alternative text I could offer for a comic would be redundant and miss out on the rich markup provided by the long description.

Here are some possibilities:

- `<img alt="" longdesc="#transcript" />`
- `<img alt="[transcript text stripped of HTML and made attribute-safe]" longdesc="#transcript" />`
- `<img alt="[Summary of comic contents... Which can get iffy, like this: 'Garfield talks about being fat. Punchline: he's fat.']" longdesc="#transcript" />`
- `<img alt="[apologize profusely to screen reader users]" longdesc="#transcript" />`

None of these seem ideal for various reasons, whether that be repeated content, no `longdesc` support, or me annoying Assistive Technology users. Without a sound declaration from folks who have thought about and dealt with this stuff way more than I have, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Maybe the alt be "alt='panel 1' longdesc='all the text'"

Comment: The solution is to make the webcomic a tasteful satire on AT. Then the last solution becomes viable ;)

Comment: Why not [figure & figcaption](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element)?

Comment: @steveax figure purports to be used for breaks in the main text, where you could take the image and replace it with a reference to that image. In this case, the image _is_ the main text, and I figure it's not appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alt` attribute is required for accessibility, and it is even formally required by the HTML 4.01 specification. The use of the `longdesc` attribute, even if it were implemented, would not make the `alt` attribute unnecessary. The description of [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) in HTML 4.01 shows the following example:

```
<IMG src="sitemap.gif"
     alt="HP Labs Site Map"
     longdesc="sitemap.html">
```

It adds: “The `alt` attribute provides a short description of the image. This should be sufficient to allow users to decide whether they want to follow the link given by the `longdesc` attribute to the longer description, here "sitemap.html".” (Whether this would be adequate even if `longdesc` were supported is a different matter.)

Due to lack of support, `longdesc` has remained useless. In order to refer to a long description, you need to use a normal link near the image. This lets anyone (even people who can see the image but may need some explanation) access the description.

Comment: Thanks for the "regular old link" solution; I feel silly for not thinking of that, but that's about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

I would think about it from the point of view of someone who needs alt-text, i.e. someone who cannot see the image.

It appears that the transcript is on the same page (from `longdesc="#transcript"`), so the 'link' that longdesc provides would take you to another section of the same page? Perhaps the transcript is further down the page?

In which case the key information for that user is what it is (very briefly), and where to find the transcript.

I would suggest something like:

`<img alt="Comic frames, full description below." longdesc="#transcript" />`

Although longdesc is getting a little more support these days and [an update to the HTML5 spec is proposed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-longdesc/), you can't rely on it yet.

Therefore if the transcript is not immediately apparent, I'd also include a link nearby to take you to it.